# I am having trouble with a mob/gravel/sand detection code

Tags: lua, minecraft

I recently tried this code for detecting things like sand gravel or mobs in ftb but when I put it with the rest of my script it messes up the whole thing and I can't see why.

The code I'm trying to add into my script:

```
local function moveForward()
  while not turtle.forward() do
      if turtle.detect() then
        turtle.dig()
        turtle.attack()
        if turtle.detect() then
            sleep(0.2)
        end
      end
  end
end
```

See [the script](http://pastebin.com/grmebgqZ) with this local function.

See my [working script](http://pastebin.com/Uf5Li1Cy) without this function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you **want** the nested `if turtle.detect() then` block?

Comment: im not to sure i just tried this and it messed up the pattern of the turtle. i just need something that if a mob walks infron for id sand/gravvle falls infront to deal with the problem and resume its progress

Comment: "it messes up" tells us next to nothing.

Comment: well its hard to explain but it sort of does the length and forgets about going back and instead of making a room as the player specified it goes sideways like in a diaganal motion evry ferw lines

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but you have set it to dig, then attack, and if it finds something still, it will sleep forever. Since it will sleep, and then sleep again because it still finds something in front of it. Also, try describing how it messes with the rest, error message, stops doing anything or other things.

try this:

```
local function moveForward()
while not turtle.forward() do
  if turtle.detect() then
    turtle.dig()
    turtle.attack()
    sleep(0.2)
    end
  end
end
```

I won't say it works, but it might fix it.

Comment: ill try it if not ima spend today looking at the dam thing lol